# Why does error: 15:73: unexpected ')' appears when I open Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, message, error-messaging

I´m getting the following error message when I open my R studio:

```
Error: 15:73: unexpected ')'
15: .libPaths(c(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"), ".R402", "library"), .libPaths()))
```

Do you have any idea how can it be removed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must have an `.Rprofile` file in the start-up directory, which has the `libPaths...` command. The command obviously has one ")" too many - just find that file, edit it and remove the last ")".

Comment: Perfect, it worked, thanks a lot for solution.